# Find characters of a set with a leading OR trailing whitespace

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write regex to match a set of characters that are proceeded or succeeded by a whitespace or other space character

So far I have `((?<=[\s\S])|(?=[\s\S]))[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+`

However in the demo below it is matching characters without a space on either side.

Any advice would be much appreciated

**Demo**

In this example the issue is `gskinner.com,` and only the comma should be matched. However the full stop is highlighted with the current regex

https://regexr.com/4ndul

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<=\s)[\p{L}\p{N}.,]+(?=\s)` https://regexr.com/4ne70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for this using alternation and look-arounds:

```
(?<=\s)[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+(?=\s)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mCgPVL/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\s)[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+`: Match a non-word non-whitespace char that is preceded by a whitespace
- `|`: OR
- `[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+(?=\s)`: Match a non-word non-whitespace char that is followed by a whitespace

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: Or just `(?<=\s)[\p{P}\p{S}]+|[\p{P}\p{S}]+(?=\s)` or `(?<=\s)([\p{P}\p{S}]+)|(?1)(?=\s)`, where `[\p{P}\p{S}]` = `[[:punct:]]`, any punctuation proper and symbols.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `(?<=\s)([\p{P}\p{S}]+)|(?1)(?=\s)` is very nice, thanks. Though I think it takes more # of steps than current one.

Answer (score 0):

Regex comes with the ability to execute conditional (if-then-else) statements. Using this, we can check to see if the character is preceded by a whitespace; else, we can check if it's followed by a whitespace. Failing this, we don't match.

`(?(?<=^|\s)\p{P}|\p{P}(?=\s|$))`

This regex checks for the start of the string or a whitespace before the characters you plan to match, and if this fails, checks for the character set followed by whitespace or the end of line. `\p{P}` looks for any kind of punctuation. **Replace `\p{P}` with whatever you would like to capture.**

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtcmcX/2/)